# WordPress using PHP7.3 in public_html, but MySQL extension error only showing in the dashboard

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I recently upgraded from PHP 7.1 to 7.3. The .htaccess files in `public_html`, `wp_content`, and `wp_includes` all show:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php5 .phtml
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php71/lib
</IfModule>
```

`wp_admin` is set to `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php`, since when I have it set to 7.3, I received the following error:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant WP_CONTENT_DIR - assumed 'WP_CONTENT_DIR' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home3/my-domain/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 141
>
> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

Following advice I found on WordPress support, I added `define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH .'wp-content');` to wp-config. That removed the Undefined Constant error, but the MySQL error remains.

Since MySQL is deprecated, I assume I don't need to download those extensions, but instead need to get WordPress to stop looking for them and use mysqli instead. But that shouldn't make a difference between 7.1 and 7.3, should it? And why does 7.3 work fine for the site, but not for the dashboard?

And if the solution ends up being over my head (I don't want to screw around with things I don't know how to fix later), will there be any problems in using 7.3 in development and production, while the dashboard uses 7.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working with HostGator's tech support, we corrected the syntax in `home/.htaccess` the following.

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

I'm assuming the change from the .php5 extension to .php7 calls the correct SQL extensions. I also removed/commented out any PHP statements in subdirectories (including wp-admin) and removed the `WP_CONTENT_DIR` definition in `wp-config`. Everything's working fine so far!

Comment: Yes, It's working for me. I just added the code in htaccess. Upvote from myside

Answer (score 0):

See the following post that explains the problem with the PHP version update to 7.3 and load.php on line 141 with MySQL.  Wordpress may have a bug that needs to be fixed.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-7-3-errors/#post-12720824

Comment: You post is better suited as a comment instead of an answer. After you have gained a certain reputation points you will be able to post comments on other questions/answers.